# Increment Varchar in db2

Tags: db2, increment, varchar

I'm trying to increment a varchar in a db2 table when I add a new line, but because the column is not only integer data, I'm having difficulty and haven't found a way to do it. To make it clear what I'm trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE (ID) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM SCHEMA.TABLE))
```

This works just fine when the id is an integer, but if it's a string (like 001A), this causes an error. What can I do to make this work even if there's a string as the max field?

Comment: First off, doing this _safely_ means that you have to serialize modifications to the table, which makes it a large bottleneck.  On concurrent systems, this is going to be a **pain**.  What do you mean by "increment" - does `'001A'` go to `'002A'` or `'001B'`?  In either case this smacks of multi-part ids, which is frowned on (violation of good normalization practices).  If these are internal ids, just use a regular, numeric, autogenid.  If external, you probably want a dedicated procedure _anyways_, so....

Comment: As Clockwork-Muse points out, this seems like a bad design. So why do you feel the need to go this route?  If you do feel the need to proceed, please indicate which type of DB2 server platform you are using, as this may affect solutions to be offered.